# Test if casting an OleVariant would raise an exception (without raising an exception)

Tags: delphi, exception, casting, variant

In Delphi I want to determine whether a particular OleVariant can be cast to a particular data type *without raising an exception if it can't*. Exceptions are not for program flow, right?

What I want is something like this, where Type could be anything supported by an OleVariant:

```
if TryVarAsType(variant, value) then ...
```

What I *don't* want is

```
try
  value := Type(variant);
  // case where the variant could be converted to a Type
except
  // case where the variant could not be converted to a Type
end;
```

The case where the variant could not be converted to a Boolean is just a normal case that occurs regularly and doesn't indicate any kind of error.

Comment: An exception is NOT an error.  An exception is an exception. It's something that is not the rule, it is the exception. The other path.  The path that might take up up the stack more than one layer. the path that requires you to write try..catch.   Having exceptions intentionally raised and routinely handled inside your application is not always "an error condition", and should not always be avoided. Sometimes, exceptions are for program flow, especially for "invalid input" conditions.

Comment: Granted an exception is an exception. But for the purposes of this question, neither code path is exceptional, and not being able to convert the variant to the given type is just as valid a condition as being able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can construct such function using the [`VariantChangeTypeEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/VarUtils.VariantChangeTypeEx) function.

```
uses
  VarUtils,
  Variants;

function TryVarAsType( AVariant : OleVariant; const AVarType: TVarType ) :Boolean;
var
   SourceType: TVarType;
begin
  SourceType:=TVarData(AVariant).VType;
  //the types are ole compatible
  if (AVarType and varTypeMask < varInt64) and (SourceType and varTypeMask < varInt64) then
    Result:=
    (SourceType=AVarType) or
    (VariantChangeTypeEx(TVarData(AVariant), TVarData(AVariant), VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, AVarType)=VAR_OK)
  else
  Result:=False; //Here you must process the variant pascal types like varString
end;
```

and use like this

```
TryVarAsType('1',varInteger);
TryVarAsType('s',varInteger)
```

this will work with only with ole compatible Variant types

```
  varEmpty    = $0000; { vt_empty        0 }
  varNull     = $0001; { vt_null         1 }
  varSmallint = $0002; { vt_i2           2 }
  varInteger  = $0003; { vt_i4           3 }
  varSingle   = $0004; { vt_r4           4 }
  varDouble   = $0005; { vt_r8           5 }
  varCurrency = $0006; { vt_cy           6 }
  varDate     = $0007; { vt_date         7 }
  varOleStr   = $0008; { vt_bstr         8 }
  varDispatch = $0009; { vt_dispatch     9 }
  varError    = $000A; { vt_error       10 }
  varBoolean  = $000B; { vt_bool        11 }
  varVariant  = $000C; { vt_variant     12 }
  varUnknown  = $000D; { vt_unknown     13 }
  varShortInt = $0010; { vt_i1          16 }
  varByte     = $0011; { vt_ui1         17 }
  varWord     = $0012; { vt_ui2         18 }
  varLongWord = $0013; { vt_ui4         19 }
  varInt64    = $0014; { vt_i8          20 }
```

for the another types (pascal variants) like `varString`, `varAny` you must check the source and destination `TVarType` and write your own test cases.

**UPDATE**

As @David point me out, the locale settings can produce different results for the same values, so you must consider this answer just as initial step or tip to construct your own function and you must aware of locale settings issues caused in the proposed function.

Comment: Nice solution. However, I think you should mention that [`VariantChangeTypeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221634.aspx) is actually an OS provided service and so will differ from the native Delphi implementation of variant type conversions. In other words this will not give the same results as the OP's exception based code.

Comment: @David, i tested the code and works ok for `ole compatible Variant types` because that i post the code. i mean if the function returns `true` the delphi cast should work ok.

Comment: @RRUZ The handling of locale dependent conversions is different. Things like integer to double will clearly be identical. But string <--> double could behave differently.

Comment: Hello regional settings hell. comma, decimal place.  Viva la difference.

Comment: I think this is probably good enough. David's counter-example is 'safe' in the sense that the VariantChangeTypeEx() seems to be a little more conservative than the Borland implementation, so getting an exception in the conversion after testing whether it should work or not should be unlikely (or should I say exceptional? ;-). (Hmm, what are the other cases where the two methods differ?)

Comment: Silly me - VariantChangeTypeEx() actually does the conversion, so there's no need to call the Borland library conversion code after finding a conversion is possible. So that eliminates any possibility that VariantChangeTypeEx() says OK but we then get an exception anyway when we actually do the conversion. Excellent answer - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of built-in support that would allow dynamic conversion checking that failed with an error code rather than an exception.

You could hand-code it yourself but doing so would produce an intolerable amount of duplication of the code in the Variants unit.  In this case I think that using exceptions is less bad than the alternative of duplicating implementation dependent code.

---

As a counter-example to RRUZ's most ingeneous answer, I offer the following code:

```
procedure Main;
var
  v: Variant;
  i: Integer;
  CanConvert: Boolean;
begin
  v := '$1';

  Writeln(BoolToStr(TryVarAsType(v, varInteger), True));

  try
    i := Integer(v);
    if i>0 then begin
      CanConvert := True;
    end;
  except
    CanConvert := False;
  end;
  Writeln(BoolToStr(CanConvert, True));
end;
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: agree. Why is it so bad to have to write try..catch around your code?

Comment: @Warren Well, it's not great to use try/except. You'd want to wrap it up in a low-level function for re-use. And it makes a mess of debugging when you have "Break on Exceptions" enabled. I suppose I'm being a little pedantic in my answer and comments, but I suppose I'm trying to consider the question in its full generality. For a very narrow type of conversion it's possible that the issues of locale may not arise.

Comment: @David, ufff, in my system your sample returns `true` and `true`. i don't know how the locale settings can influence the result for the `$1` string.

Comment: @RRUZ That example is not about locale. That's about $1 being a special type of string representation of a hex integer that is understood by StrToInt, but not by system conversion. Not sure why our machines differ though!! Do you appreciate my (rather pedantic) point though? It's easy enough to construct other failure modes.

Comment: @David, i don't have any problem with discuss about are point of view  so don't worry to be pedantic, and about the conversion in my machine i found why returns `true`and `true` is because which the currency simbol on my system is `$` , if i change the currency symbol to `€` the sample which you provides works ok. so i accept your point the answer should mention which the locale settings can be generate different results for the same values. ;)

Comment: @Warren, eight years later, I've got the same question as the OP. One reason to avoid exceptions is performance, particularly for Win32. One example is a lookup against a list of tens of thousands of values, and the value being looked up is not variant compatible with the values in the list. You get tens of thousands of exceptions. That is a performance hit, especially for Win32. I'd rather have a VarIsEqual that first determines if the values can be compared. If not, it returns False without an exception ever raised.

Comment: Unfortunately Jon, Variant equivalence is an application specific thing.   You might want to treat doubles and currencies the same, say, or treat them different or have a general epsilon (comparison threshold) or special rules, or treat unicode string and non unicode strings as equal, or not to.     Exceptions happen when conversions and casting all fails.

Even if you think you have an exception free code path, and high performance, leave the exception catchers in if you use variants. You can't predict all the failures.